# How to start Windows Terminal and run git bash command immediately?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-terminal

I would like to automatically run a command in Windows Terminal when it starts for bash tab.
How to do that?

I'm trying to use "command" in json options, but it doesn't work:

```js
{
  "guid": "{2ece5bfe-50ed-5f3a-ab87-5cd4baafed2b}",
  "hidden": false,
  "name": "Git Bash",
  "source": "Git",
  "command": "npm run e"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these modifications in your settings file:

```javascript
{
  "name": "git bash",
  "source": "git",
  "commandline": "bash.exe -i -c 'npm run e; exec bash'"
}
```

The command `bash.exe -i -c 'npm run e; exec bash'` ensures that npm runs the command and then opens a bash session. If you simply run the npm command, the terminal would close after its execution.

I excluded the `guid` and `hidden` keys for brevity, but may still be required for your setup.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but now I get an error:

[error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `bash.exe -i -c 'npm run e; exec bash'']

Comment: It looks like error `0x80070002` means that windows couldn't find the file. In this case, probably `bash.exe`. You could include the full path in the `commandLine` argument, something like `"commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe -i -c 'npm run e; exec bash'"` or ensure that this directory is included in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I made a: `"commandline": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe -i -c 'npm run e; exec bash'"`  and it works, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. One last minor point, I noticed that you updated the question to include the text. Thank you for doing that! However, when you pasted in the text, you actually pasted in command that included the solution, instead of the original command. I think it would be best if the question indicated the original problems. Thanks for posting and have a great day.

Comment: Ok, I edited it, although that version I pasted also didn't work, since I don't have a bash in environment variables ;]